# Swift / how to parse data and save as pairs to core data

Tags: ios, swift

I have a blog with entries having two attributes. "eventDate" & "title".
I have the following code to download the "eventDate":

```
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if elementName == "item" {
        currentEvent = EventPosts()

        return
    }

    if elementName == "eventDate" {
        parsedElement = "eventDates"
    }

    if elementName == "title" {
        parsedElement = "title"
    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    let str = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

    if parsedElement == "eventDates" && str != "" {
        if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty {

            currentEvent.eventDates = str
            parsedElement = ""

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Calendar", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
            let datum = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
            datum.setValue(currentEvent.eventDates, forKey: "date")

            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                dates.append(datum)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now I want to save the matching "title" into the matching core data entity called Calendar.

This code is what I have tried, but I guess it does not create matching pairs. It only creates Calendar entries with eventDates and Calendar entries with title, but not with both and matching pairs...

```
    if parsedElement == "eventDates" && str != "" {
        if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty {

            currentEvent.eventDates = str
            parsedElement = ""

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Calendar", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
            let datum = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
            datum.setValue(currentEvent.eventDates, forKey: "date")

            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                dates.append(datum)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }

    }

    if parsedElement == "title" && str != "" {
        if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty {

            currentEvent.eventDates = str
            parsedElement = ""

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Calendar", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
            let title = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
            title.setValue(currentEvent.title, forKey: "title")

            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                dates.append(title)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }

    }
```

What is the correct code to create an entity of Calendar with the matching pair of "title" and "eventDate"? Help is very appreciated.

**EDIT** That was tryed so far:

```
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if elementName == "item" {
        currentEvent = EventPosts()

        return
    }

    if elementName == "eventDate" {
        parsedElement = "eventDates"
        print(currentEvent.eventDates)
    }

    if elementName == "title" {
        parsedElement = "title"
        print(currentEvent.title)
    }

    if !currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty && !currentEvent.title.isEmpty {

        parsedElement = ""

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Calendar", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
        let datum = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)


        datum.setValue(currentEvent.eventDates, forKey: "date")
        datum.setValue(currentEvent.title, forKey: "title")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            dates.append(datum)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    } else if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty && !currentEvent.title.isEmpty {
        print("currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty")
    } else if !currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty && currentEvent.title.isEmpty {
        print("currentEvent.title.isEmpty")
    } else {
        print("both.isEmpty")
    }
}
```

Console says both.isEmpty million times with this code. But please remember: with my first code I had the eventDates perfectly saved!

Comment: If the `eventDate` and `title` are parsed consecutively you might create a temporary struct. If it's `nil` create an instance and put one of the values in. If the other value is parsed (the struct object is not `nil`) create the `NSManagedObject` passing both values and reset the struct object to `nil`.

Comment: EventsPosts() is a struct

Comment: how I am creating the NSManagedObject with both values? that is exactly my problem

Comment: see Phillip's answer :-)

Comment: please notice my edit.

Comment: You're just printing the values rather than putting them into the `EventPost()` instance as Phillip suggested.

Comment: working now. thank you very much Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes you only want to save an object if both pieces of information are available.  The idea is to move the creation of the managed object to be after the parsing.

```
    if parsedElement == "eventDates" && str != "" {
        if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty {
            currentEvent.eventDates = str
            parsedElement = ""
        }
    }

    if parsedElement == "title" && str != "" {
        if currentEvent.title.isEmpty {
            currentEvent.title = str
            parsedElement = ""
        }
    }

    if !currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty && !currentEvent.title.isEmpty {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Calendar", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
        let datum = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        datum.setValue(currentEvent.eventDates, forKey: "date")
        datum.setValue(currentEvent.title, forKey: "title")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            dates.append(datum)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: my tableview stays empty. to test I have entered `print("teststring")` before the row `datum.setValue(currentEvent.eventDates, forKey: "date")`. Since I can't find "teststring" within the debug, I assume that the if loop is not entered?

Comment: every eventDate (as customfield) has a title

Comment: I have added an else block with `print("ERRORERROR")`and yes. the else block is entered. but what am I missing?

Comment: now it works. I had to edit it to: `if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty && currentEvent.title.isEmpty`

Comment: no sorry. doesnt answer my question since it does make it worse. I have now almost countless empty rows...

Comment: In your original code, you updated properties of `currentEvent`.  That seems to be removed from your edited version.

Comment: yeah yeah. you are totally right. I have made a little mess. with your code now it is working properly. only issue now is, that I have every event 5 times listed. any idea?

Comment: Do you mean duplicate objects are being put into your storage or is it a visual thing?

Comment: I think it is an saving issue, because if I print `print(dates)` within the do block with `dates = results as! [NSManagedObject]` I have listed the events 3-5 times each

Comment: <NSManagedObject: 0x7fd0da57ead0> (entity: Calendar; id: 0xd000000004600000 <x-coredata://2CADABA2-29CB-4DE3-B221-7709A1582DCE/Calendar/p280> ; data: {
    date = "14.04.2016";
    title = "MiSery at Crowns Club in Munich";

Comment: <NSManagedObject: 0x7fd0da69c870> (entity: Calendar; id: 0xd000000004640000 <x-coredata://2CADABA2-29CB-4DE3-B221-7709A1582DCE/Calendar/p281> ; data: {
    date = "14.04.2016";
    title = "MiSery at Crowns Club in Munich";

Comment: <NSManagedObject: 0x7fd0da441e60> (entity: Calendar; id: 0xd000000004680000 <x-coredata://2CADABA2-29CB-4DE3-B221-7709A1582DCE/Calendar/p282> ; data: {
    date = "14.04.2016";
    title = "MiSery at Crowns Club in Munich";

Comment: just for example, 3 different objects with the same content

Comment: Do you print the source information anywhere before you start parsing to see if there are repeated elements in it?

Comment: do you mean repeated elements on the blog? not possible. I've created it hours ago and it should be perfectly clean.

Comment: The code probably shouldn't be inside `didStartElement`.  What if you only create an array of `EventPost` objects while parsing and then use that array to save managed objects when you reach the end of the document?

Comment: well the code is inside `func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)` not within didStartElement

Comment: so I'm pretty sure the end of the document IS reached at this point. isn't it? or shouldn't it be?

Comment: I have a `parserDidEndDocument`where I reload the view and stuff like that. I will try to save the objects there.

Comment: well entered at `func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {` I only have the last event presented now... didn't really did the job

Comment: Did you miss the "create an array of EventPost objects while parsing" part of the suggestion?

Comment: entering the code at: `func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {` did it. thank you very much. I hope you're getting way more upvotes. thank you